# How to prevent axis zerolines from vanishing?

Tags: r, plotly

So I'm 'm attempting to create a line chart in Plotly on R, using data that contains NA values so that Plotly doesn't start the line until it gets to a non-zero value. This works pretty well, yet it makes the zeroline of the x-axis disappear, and even using `zeroline = TRUE` has proven useless to counter whatever Plotly is doing... Is there any reason for that ?

[Graph with no zeroline on either axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2EVJ.jpg)

Here is the code I have wrote to render it :

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

dataBeverage <- data.table(
    month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12),
    volume = c(NA, NA, NA, 3000, 2450, 3200, 4678, 2435, 1342, 1731, 2340, 3500))

p <- plot_ly(data = dataBeverage, x = ~month, y = ~volume, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', line = list(color='#17BECF', shape = 'spline'))%>%
    layout(
        hovermode = 'x unified', separators = ', ',
        xaxis = list(
            range = c(min(dataBeverage$month),max(dataBeverage$month)),
            title = '',
            tickangle=-40,
            ticktext = list('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'Octobre', 'November', 'December'),
            tickvals = list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12),
            showgrid = FALSE
        ),
        yaxis = list(
            title = list(text = 'Montly volume', standoff = 15L),
            ticksuffix = ' hL',
            tickformat = ',d'
        ))
p
```

I know I could always add a trace with `x = range(dataBeverage$month)` and `y = 0` but then even when I add `hovermode = 'none'` to that trace, It still somehow shows "trace 0 : 0 hL" on the control-tip when hovering on January or December.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending the y-axis to 0 can be done with `rangemode = "tozero"`.

`zeroline = TRUE` will only work when the value 0 is already shown on the axis. And will determine if a horizontal line is drawn.

```
p <- plot_ly(data = dataBeverage, x = ~month, y = ~volume, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', line = list(color='#17BECF', shape = 'spline'))%>%
  layout(
    hovermode = 'x unified', separators = ', ',
    xaxis = list(
      range = c(min(dataBeverage$month),max(dataBeverage$month)),
      title = '',
      tickangle=-40,
      ticktext = list('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'Octobre', 'November', 'December'),
      tickvals = list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12),
      showgrid = FALSE
    ),
    yaxis = list(
      title = list(text = 'Montly volume', standoff = 15L),
      ticksuffix = ' hL',
      tickformat = ',d',
      rangemode = "tozero"  #includes 0 on axis
    ))
p
```

[image]